# Option to "open with..." on folders in finder

Tags: finder, folders

Is it possible to add the "Open with..." option to Finder, when you do a secondary click on a folder? I want the same behavior as when I'm secondary clicking on a file.

**Edit**

I do not want to open the contents of the folder with the application, but simply just the folder.

Try dragging one of your folders over all docked applications. Some of them will show that they can open a folder.

Example:

- BBEdit - Allow you to browse the contents of the folder in the sidebar and edit each file inside it.
- iTerm - Starts the command line inside the opened folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the folder to a bundle, i.e. if you set the bundle bit with...

```
SetFile -a B /path/to/folder
```

...you will then get the option to "Open with..." in Finder's control-click.

To remove the bundle bit again, use the same command as above with a lower case "b" instead of the capital "B".
Photos uses this method to make its directory double-clickable.

For reference see also:
[A folder's bundle bit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329871/remove-program-association-from-directory/329876#329876)