# Finder opens Terminal when clicking on homedir icon

Tags: terminal, finder

I have added an icon for my homedir to Finder.

However, when I click on it, Terminal opens instead of the expected Finder view of `$HOME`.

Is there some sort of file type or other metadata that has somehow become incorrect for the homedir icon? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: How exactly did you add the icon?

Comment: Via Finder > Preferences I think

Comment: Sounds a bit like this (with the difference of the directory being "Downloads"): https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329871/remove-program-association-from-directory/329876#329876

Comment: @Redarm This is correct. Thank you so much. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory can become a "Package", if the bundle bit has been set for some reason by either another program, or the user.
"Kind: Package" will then be visible in the "Get Info" window and it can be opened by the application set in the same window.

Some applications prefer (or create) a package instead of a directory, which can be double clicked to open a whole library folder in an application (iPhoto for example).
 
It may also make the user think twice to directly access and edit its contents.

To remove the bit from the home directory run the following command in Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app, or search in Spotlight):

```
SetFile -a b ~
```

SetFile is part of the command line tools. Without the command line tools installed, a popup should ask you if you want to download them. Allow this and try again.