# iCloud Drive Folder in Unknown Format

Tags: macos, icloud

This afternoon I was trying to copy a file into an iCloud folder which held a number of .epub books. Somehow I did something that caused the folder to become unrecognizable as a folder. Have no idea WTH I did but I can't access any of the contents and is is showing up as some sort of odd file. I suspect I inadvertently scrambled the attributes or metadata associated with the folder. I have attached a screenshot of the Get Info for what now appears to be a file of some sort.

I would greatly welcome any ideas on how to get out of this jam.

[image: Get Info]

Comment: It does still state Kind "Folder" in your screenshot. If you double-click the file/folder in Finder, what error do you get? Have you tried using Terminal to to open the folder with "cd <path>" (you can enter "cd " and then drag and drop the file into the Terminal window)?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin, I can 'ls' the directory in terminal and it appears to have most if not all of the files in it. When I double clicked on the file and attempted to open it in Finder the following happened, 1) the iCloud Drive icon in the left side of the Finder repeatedly showed the little animation indicating it was downloading but  I could not find the documents anywhere, 2) my keyboard became unresponsive mouse worked but not the keyboard, ultimately had to Force Quit Finder to restore keyboard control.

Comment: Just had a discovery, if I select the file in Finder and Right Click on it one of the options is "Show Package Contents" If I select that it shows me all of my files. It seems whatever I did originally "converted" the contents of that folder or the folder itself into a package. I'm simply going to create a new folder and copy the contents into it and call it a day.... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Could you share the terminal output  of given for the folder with "ls -la"?

Comment: @Qwikatb Even though your screenshot shows the directory recognized as folder, the "Show Package Content" could be this issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361141/49869